# maximum recursion depth when searching python object - requests

Tags: python, python-requests

This code works well when running from a python terminal. However, when running inside a DCC called Nuke - ( compositing software in vfx ), this gives recursion error. Totally blank on why this occurs.

```
import requests
url = 'xxxxxxxx.com/my_work'
data = {'field_to_query_01': 4444, 'field_to_query_02': 'Pending'}
requests.get(url, data)
```

I tried setting sys recursionLimit to 1500 but still the error occurs. Setting recursionlimit is not advisable as i read in some posts here.

Also changed requests to 2.7 instead of 2.11 which is compatible with python 2.7. Yet this error occurs.

I found that this issue could be because of version conflict. Changed to requests 2.7 which is found on google search to be the one for python 2.7
Yet this issue occurs. Any remote clue ?

```
File "\\xxx.xxx.xx.xxx\Scripts\python_portable\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 451, in request
prep = self.prepare_request(req)
File "\\xxx.xxx.xx.xxx\Scripts\python_portable\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 378, in prepare_request
headers=merge_setting(request.headers, self.headers, dict_class=CaseInsensitiveDict),
File "\\xxx.xxx.xx.xxx\Scripts\python_portable\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 62, in merge_setting
merged_setting = dict_class(to_key_val_list(session_setting))
File "\\xxx.xxx.xx.xxx\Scripts\python_portable\site-packages\requests\structures.py", line 46, in __init__
self.update(data, **kwargs)
File "C:\Program Files\Nuke12.2v10\python27.zip\_abcoll.py", line 564, in update
File "C:\Program Files\Nuke12.2v10\python27.zip\abc.py", line 144, in __instancecheck__
File "C:\Program Files\Nuke12.2v10\python27.zip\abc.py", line 180, in __subclasscheck__
File "C:\Program Files\Nuke12.2v10\python27.zip\abc.py", line 180, in __subclasscheck__
File "C:\Program Files\Nuke12.2v10\pythonextensions\site-packages\shiboken2\files.dir\shibokensupport\typing27.py", line 1338, in __subclasscheck__
return super(GenericMeta, self).__subclasscheck__(cls)
File "C:\Program Files\Nuke12.2v10\python27.zip\abc.py", line 161, in __subclasscheck__
File "C:\Program Files\Nuke12.2v10\pythonextensions\site-packages\shiboken2\files.dir\shibokensupport\typing27.py", line 1070, in __extrahook__
if issubclass(subclass, scls):
File "P:\python_portable\site-packages\typing.py", line 1410, in __subclasscheck__
return super(GenericMeta, self).__subclasscheck__(cls)
File "C:\Program Files\Nuke12.2v10\python27.zip\abc.py", line 161, in __subclasscheck__
File "P:\python_portable\site-packages\typing.py", line 1140, in __extrahook__
if issubclass(subclass, scls):
File "C:\Program Files\Nuke12.2v10\pythonextensions\site-packages\shiboken2\files.dir\shibokensupport\typing27.py", line 1338, in __subclasscheck__
return super(GenericMeta, self).__subclasscheck__(cls)
File "C:\Program Files\Nuke12.2v10\python27.zip\abc.py", line 161, in __subclasscheck__
File "C:\Program Files\Nuke12.2v10\pythonextensions\site-packages\shiboken2\files.dir\shibokensupport\typing27.py", line 1070, in __extrahook__
if issubclass(subclass, scls):
File "P:\python_portable\site-packages\typing.py", line 1410, in __subclasscheck__
return super(GenericMeta, self).__subclasscheck__(cls)
File "C:\Program Files\Nuke12.2v10\python27.zip\abc.py", line 161, in __subclasscheck__
File "P:\python_portable\site-packages\typing.py", line 1140, in __extrahook__
if issubclass(subclass, scls):
File "C:\Program Files\Nuke12.2v10\pythonextensions\site-packages\shiboken2\files.dir\shibokensupport\typing27.py", line 1338, in __subclasscheck__
return super(GenericMeta, self).__subclasscheck__(cls)
File "C:\Program Files\Nuke12.2v10\python27.zip\abc.py", line 161, in __subclasscheck__
File "C:\Program Files\Nuke12.2v10\pythonextensions\site-packages\shiboken2\files.dir\shibokensupport\typing27.py", line 1070, in __extrahook__
if issubclass(subclass, scls):
File "P:\python_portable\site-packages\typing.py", line 1410, in __subclasscheck__
return super(GenericMeta, self).__subclasscheck__(cls)
File "C:\Program Files\Nuke12.2v10\python27.zip\abc.py", line 161, in __subclasscheck__
File "P:\python_portable\site-packages\typing.py", line 1140, in __extrahook__
if issubclass(subclass, scls):
File "C:\Program Files\Nuke12.2v10\pythonextensions\site-packages\shiboken2\files.dir\shibokensupport\typing27.py", line 1338, in __subclasscheck__
return super(GenericMeta, self).__subclasscheck__(cls)
File "C:\Program Files\Nuke12.2v10\python27.zip\abc.py", line 161, in __subclasscheck__
File "C:\Program Files\Nuke12.2v10\pythonextensions\site-packages\shiboken2\files.dir\shibokensupport\typing27.py", line 1070, in __extrahook__
```

Comment: This doesn't appear to be an issue with requests itself, but with Shiboken2 and PySide2 and an additional Typing module being imported.  Here's a related bug report: https://bugreports.qt.io/plugins/servlet/mobile#issue/PYSIDE-1073

Comment: True. their are some custom modules that load PySide2 and then their is an already existing PySide2 in nuke. How to rewire to avoid loading PySide2 from custom module. I have seen that when sys modules does not contain qtpy( which also has PySide2 ) then everything works smooth

Comment: Not entirely clear.  On the bug report the dev indicated he would patch PySide2 and the issue was closed, and that post was in August 2019, so it *should* be fixed.  From his proposed workarounds it sounds like adding the following to the start of your script `try: import typing; except ImportError: from PySide2.support.signature import typing' may work.  
  Or, if you can update to Python3 and Nuke13 that might avoid the whole issue, but would probably require a lot of additional refactoring. https://erwanleroy.com/updating-your-python-scripts-for-nuke-13/

Comment: Sorry for late response. This was solved a long while ago. Issue happened to be with conflicting versions of pathlib module found in multiple places in the system. Moment I kept one, the error disappeared